# PHP: parse file_get_contents string into multiple arrays?

Tags: php

I have a log file which is in the following format:

```
-----------------------------------------------
line containing text 
another line containing text 
another line containing text 
another line containing text 
another line containing text 
-----------------------------------------------
line containing text 
another line containing text 
another line containing text 
another line containing text 
another line containing text 
-----------------------------------------------
```

What I am attmpting to do is read the entire text file into a string, then parse the string results into arrays, with each array containing the data between the lines starting with "-----------------" and the final result being a multidimensional array. 
Example:

```
-----------------------------------------------
'start new array here'
line containing text '<-- element[0]'
another line containing text '<-- element[1]'
another line containing text '<-- element[2]'
another line containing text '<-- element[3]'
another line containing text '<-- element[4]'
*'end array here'*
-----------------------------------------------
*'start new array here'*
line containing text '<-- element[0]
another line containing text '<-- element[1]'
another line containing text '<-- element[2]'
another line containing text '<-- element[3]'
another line containing text '<-- element[4]'
*'end array here'* 
-----------------------------------------------
```

with the end result being

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => line containing text
            [1] => another line containing text
            [2] => another line containing text
            [3] => another line containing text
            [4] => another line containing text
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => line containing text
            [1] => another line containing text
            [2] => another line containing text
            [3] => another line containing text
            [4] => another line containing text
        )
 )
```

So my question is how can I acomplish this in an efficient manner? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP explode

```
$contents = file_get_contents('file.txt');

$data = array();
if(!empty($contents)){
    $temp = explode("-----------------------------------------------\n", $contents);                
    if(!empty($temp)){
        foreach($temp as $v){
            if(!empty($v)){
                $data[] = explode("\n", $v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you may need to loop through the data to remove the last -------------  if there's no newline after it.

Comment: This worked great.. I guess I was overthinking what I was trying to do.. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file with fopen, then use fgets to read/parse the file line by line: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

If you don't need to keep the whole dataset in memory for use later (ie. you can perform an operation on a subset, discard it then move onto the next) then this would use less memory.

Answer (score 0):

#### Something simpler like this...

```
<?php
$arr = file('somefile.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$i=0;
foreach(array_slice($arr,1,count($arr)-2) as $v)
{
    (strpos($v,'-')!==false) ?  $i++ :  $new_arr[$i][]=$v;
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => line containing text 
            [1] => another line containing text 
            [2] => another line containing text 
            [3] => another line containing text 
            [4] => another line containing text 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => line containing text 
            [1] => another line containing text 
            [2] => another line containing text 
            [3] => another line containing text 
            [4] => another line containing text 
        )

)
```